# get data with query from document collection and document subcollection in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with "grup" name and have a subcollection named "anggota".

Please help me, how to display data by query referring to collection document and subcollection document.

Firestore collection:

[image: collections in my firestore]

I've tried with this query but it doesn't work, the data doesn't appear

```
db.collection("grup").document().collection("anggota")
            .whereEqualTo("iduser", idUser)
            .orderBy("updatetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> list = value.getDocuments();

                datalist.clear();
                for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                    final Modelfirestore c = d.toObject(Modelfirestore.class);
                    datalist.add(c);
                    
                }
                mAdapterss.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following query:

```
                              
db.collection("grup").document().collection("anggota")
        .whereEqualTo("iduser", idUser)
        .orderBy("updatetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

It means that you are creating a reference to a document with a random ID. Calling [CollectionReferenc#document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) method, without passing any arguments:

> Returns a DocumentReference pointing to a new document with an auto-generated ID within this collection.

So to be able to query the documents within the `anggota` subcollection you have to pass the document ID to the `document()` method like this:

```
                                 
db.collection("grup").document("8FDD...").collection("anggota")
        .whereEqualTo("iduser", idUser)
        .orderBy("updatetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Comment: that's not what I mean, I understand about that.

but, I want to display data from subcollections and collections with clauses taken from fields in collections and fields in subcollections